# how to bind each each interface to a separate VPN config

Tags: linux, networking, routing, vpn

What I am trying to do is route all traffic that comes on a given interface to a specific, per interface, VPN connection where all outbound traffic is actually leaving on WAN0.

I frankly don't have a notion where to start. I was thinking a VLAN per interface where there is only one route out of that VLAN and that's over the VPN connection. But then I tried to think how I could manage 4 disparate VPN connections and I got lost.

The desired traffic flow is:

- eth0 -> VPN1
- eth1 -> VPN2
- eth2 -> VPN3
- eth3 -> VPN4

  VPN{1,2,3,4} -> WAN0